# Ошибка 400 (Bad request) при работе виджета через AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

Возможно, тема уже избитая, но всё же...

Есть такой плагин:

```
define('PLUGIN_DIR', plugin_dir_path(__FILE__));
include 'AtWidget.php';

class AjaxTest
{

    private $textRes;

    public function AjaxTest()
    {

    }

    // End Widget
    public function add_ajax_action()
    {        
        add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_testajaxaction', array(
            &$this,
            'test_ajax_action'
        ));
    }

    public function test_ajax_action()
    {
        echo "It's working!";
        wp_die();
    }

    public function test_ajax_widget_registration()
    {
        add_action("widgets_init", function () {
            register_widget("AtWidget");
        });
    }
}

$instance = new AjaxTest();
$instance->add_ajax_action();
$instance->test_ajax_widget_registration();
```

И виджет к нему:

```
class AtWidget extends WP_Widget
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct("at_widget", "Тестовый виджет для Ajax на сайте", array(
            “description” => "Тестовый виджет для Ajax на сайте"
        ));
    }

    public function widget($args, $instance)
    {
        $title = $instance[“title”];
        ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
            function SendTestAjaxRequest()
            {                
                    var caNonce = document.getElementById('ca_nonce_test_ajax').value;
                    var ajaxurl ="http://wptest/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php";
                    var data ={action: 'testajaxaction', ca_nonce_: caNonce};
                    $.post(ajaxurl,data , function (data) {
                        alert(data);
                    });

            }
        </script>
<form onSubmit="return false;">
        <?php wp_nonce_field('test-ajax-action', 'ca_nonce_test_ajax'); ?>
            <input type="submit" id="test_at_widget_submit"
        name="test_at_widget_submit" onclick="SendTestAjaxRequest()"
        value="Test">
</form>
<?php
    }
}
```

Вроде всё делаю по документации, но почему-то всё равно получается ошибка 400. Где я ошибся?

P.S. Использую OpenServer. Виджет находится на сайте. Не в админке.

Comment: Это `var ajaxurl ="http://wptest/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php";` правильный адрес? Что показывают логи сервера?

Comment: Виджет где - в админке? А почему nopriv?

Comment: Ошибка 400 (Bad Request) – это код ответа HTTP, который означает, что сервер не смог обработать запрос, отправленный клиентом. Я не знаком с вордпрессом но обычно . такая ошибка возникает из за того что скрипт ожидает получить определенные данные от клиента и не получает их или получает не в таком виде как ожидает. Также такой статус отправляет сервер когда валидируется форма и пользователь вводит не верно данные!

Comment: @KAGGDesign, виджет на сайте. Не в админке.

Comment: Ладно, сейчас отдебажу. Уже самому интересно.

Comment: Разобрался сам. См. ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Короче, всё-таки разобрался сам.

Дело оказалось в том, что хуки `wp_ajax_nopriv` работают **только если пользователь не залогинен**. А, пытаюсь отправить запрос с сайта будучи залогинен. Поэтому ничего и не работало.

Чтобы AJAX запрос работал во всех случаях нужно ставить сразу два хука.

```
public function add_ajax_action()
{        
    add_action('wp_ajax_testajaxaction', array(
        &$this,
        'test_ajax_action'
    ));
    add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_testajaxaction', array(
        &$this,
        'test_ajax_action'
    ));
}
```

К сожалению, в документации об этом написано не совсем ясно. Но, тем не менее...

Comment: Совершенно верно, я с самого начала это говорил.

Answer (score 1):

Вот полностью рабочий код (поместил его как файл в папку mu-plugins).

Здесь главное - два хука: `wp_ajax_testajaxaction` и `wp_ajax_nopriv_testajaxaction`.

```
<?php

class AtWidget extends WP_Widget {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct( "at_widget", "Тестовый виджет для Ajax на сайте", [
            'description' => "Тестовый виджет для Ajax на сайте",
        ] );
    }

    public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
        $title = isset( $instance[ 'title' ] ) ? $instance[ 'title' ] : '';
        ?>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp'></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function SendTestAjaxRequest() {
                var caNonce = document.getElementById( 'ca_nonce_test_ajax' ).value;
                var ajaxurl = "<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); ?>";
                var data    = { action: 'testajaxaction', ca_nonce_: caNonce };
                jQuery.post( ajaxurl, data, function( data ) {
                    alert( data );
                } );
            }
        </script>
        <form onSubmit="return false;">
            <?php wp_nonce_field( 'test-ajax-action', 'ca_nonce_test_ajax' ); ?>
            <input type="submit" id="test_at_widget_submit"
                   name="test_at_widget_submit" onclick="SendTestAjaxRequest()"
                   value="Test">
        </form>
        <?php
    }
}

class AjaxTest {

    private $textRes;

    // End Widget
    public function add_ajax_action() {
        add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_testajaxaction', [ $this, 'test_ajax_action' ] );
        add_action( 'wp_ajax_testajaxaction', [ $this, 'test_ajax_action' ] );
    }

    public function test_ajax_action() {
        echo "It's working!";
        exit();
    }

    public function test_ajax_widget_registration() {
        add_action( "widgets_init", function () {
            register_widget( "AtWidget" );
        } );
    }
}

$instance = new AjaxTest();
$instance->add_ajax_action();
$instance->test_ajax_widget_registration();
```